# Is there any performance difference between M.2 and 2.5in SSD form factors?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, m.2

I am currently looking at SSD options for a computer build. I have come across two identical drives that come in a traditional 2.5in laptop hard drive package and a M.2 board. **Will there be any performance difference, given that they both are SATA drives? How about longevity?**

These are the drives I am looking at:

- [SD8SN8U-128G-1122 (M.2)](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/SanDisk/SD8SN8U-128G-1122/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsSk9nu1rLV0I7CW%2flwA7HUUXpWk4eSRQ8H%2fsBtmVVrFA%3d%3d)
- [SD8SB8U-128G-1122 (2.5in)](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/SanDisk/SD8SB8U-128G-1122/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsSk9nu1rLV0I7CW%2flwA7HU3AqmgaUipFMbQ77hDyGU9Q%3d%3d)

The datasheet claims claims these drives have an endurance of 72TBW. **Where does this fall compared to the average?**

Comment: The physical size of the devices won't impact performance.  They may be using different components, controllers, but that should be clear from the data sheets at the links.  You'd have to research the parts, and research the endurance of similar products to get your answers.

Comment: I presume you mean SATA 3 M.2 drives vs 2.5" drives?  There is no performance difference between SATA 3 vs SATA 3 drives if your wondering

Comment: Thanks. Those answered my first question. Both use SATA3. One thing I am wondering: Will connection via cable vs directly to the motherboard will affect performance?

Comment: @CalebReister You'll see no tangible difference between SATA3 cable vs direct SATA3 connection to motherboard. Unless the cable is bad in which case the SATA controller might fall back to SATA1/2 speeds.